# random string from a sequence

Tags: python, random

Is there a way to randomize a set string, like you can for integers?

I'll give an example:

```
import random
random.randint(1, 30) #will produce random number between 1 and 30
```

And for a string I would like to randomize words from a set variable:

```
a="off","it","on","not"
random.randstr(a) #I understand that this isnt a real code and will produce and error
```

Is there an easy way to make this possible?

Comment: replace `randstr` by `choice` and off you go.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this, it's the idiomatic solution:

```
import random
a = ['off', 'it', 'on', 'not']
random.choice(a)
=> 'on' # just an example, it's a random output
```

The above code makes use of the `choice()` function, take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) for additional details.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
a = ["off","it","on","not"]
a[random.randint(0, len(a))]
```